# C: pointer of char & segmantation fault

Tags: c

In the next code:

```
char i,*p;
i = 65;
p = &i;
p = (char *) 66;
(*p)++;
printf("%d",p);
```

I got segmentation fault. I didn't understand why. I have a pointer to a char (in this case char 66=C), and then I change it value, which is also 66 - to 67. Are the values of char "protected" from this change? Is it happen also with others, except char?

I tried to understand the idea that stand behind this thing (and not only fix it). Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the problem:

```
p = (char *) 66;
```

It should be:

```
*p = 66;
```

`p` is a pointer to a `char`, so you cannot assign values like `66` to it. You can derefernce `p` in order to assign values to where the pointer "looks".

If you want to print the value where `p` points to, you must use again the dereference operator (`*`) like this:

```
printf("%d", *p); // prints the value where p points to
```

If you want to print the pointer address you can do this:

```
printf("%p", p); // prints the address where p points
```

Comment: `(Char) 66`??? Why is is `Char` capitalized? And why use a cast here at all instead of a plain `*p = 66`?

Comment: Char was capitalized my mistake. removed it anyway.

Comment: The OP probably also wants to use `*p` in the `printf()` call.

Answer (score 1):

A character pointer doesn't store a character, it stores an address where a character can be found.  So

```
p = (char *)66;
```

says that p points to address number 66, where a character can be found.  Odds are that address isn't even accessible by your program, much less that it stores a character.